# DocuSign : Different Account Id formats in account information api and webhook notification?

Tags: docusignapi

We are using OAuth2 to authenticate the users to DocuSign, after the authentication we use the AccountsApi call to get account information to get the account id of the logged in user. This is in the form of "ecsddfbfa5-13d2-4e8e-c49e-a214r166b987", so we save this login information. Now, when we receive the webhook notification on completion of an envelope, we get the account id as part of the custom fields and this is in the form of "7657898" (numeric). The issue is that we can't map the notifications with the user that initiated the signing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of ensuring the account ID that you get from DS event notification is the same as the one that was used to login is to do a `GET /v2/accounts/{numericAccountId}` and compare its response.accountIdGuid with the one you got at login-time (most-likely from GET /oauth/userinfo).
See https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/Accounts/get/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we couldn't find any other way till your suggestion, but we have started using email id of the account now, the event notification have the email id.